# How to filter a Collection filter by two strings in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Imagine I have a Collection of ids like:

```
[1,11,21]
[1,5,6]
[11,35,56]
```

I need to filter the Collection in order only to get the field which contains both 1 and 11. By doing a search.in I get 1 OR 11.

What would be the correct way of performing a filter to get fields with 1 AND 11?

Answer (score 2):

You can formulate a filter expression like -

```
$filter=fieldname/any(t: t eq '1') and fieldname/any(t: t eq '11')
```

where fieldname would be the field of Collection type. This would filter the fields that have both 1 and 11 in the collection. You can refer to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/odata-expression-syntax-for-azure-search) for other supported OData expressions in Azure Search.

Note that Azure Search Index currently supports Collection(Edm.String). If you want a collection of other primitive types for the ids, there is a feature which is in private preview at the moment. Shoot me an email if you want to try it out.

Comment: @Carlos If you found this useful, can you mark this as an answer.